# Tool to maintain IBM x3650 - get info from faulty HW

Tags: virtualization, hardware, xen, xenserver, ibm-xseries

I am have a server IBM x3650 M4 running XenServer and Windows guest. The server have a problem with harddrive, yellow exclamation mark blinking. I am able to turn off the server go to BIOS and get some brief info. The info is very brief and not explanatory :/

I would like to have some tool allowing me to check server status from windows guest. Something like DELL server manager. I Have found IBM® ToolsCenter Suite unfortunately it asks me for user name / password and defeaults does not work. Is this the right tool or should I use something else? Can this bypass XenServer between hardware and guest system? Or is there any other way how to get info from the server without restarting it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A hypervisor, Xen in this case, is there to "protect" your hosts hardware from the guest OS'es under all circumstances.

So, no, you will not be able to get detailed hardware information out of your *guest* machines. The oly machine you can use to 'speak' to the hardware ist the host OS, So Xen in this case. Look for Xen management agents which you can then acces from the guest VMs.

Answer (score 0):

For constant monitoring, the answer by bjoster is your solution. For a one shot troubleshooting attempt: Boot Linux from a live CD/USB drive and use it to check your hardware.